# Can I get count from a hash_map while adding some items to it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, hashmap

For both windows and linux:

In multi-threaded application, in case I do not care the very exactly when getting the count of a hash_map, then can I safely call {hash_map}.size() while still allow other threads to add/delete items on that {hash_map}?

Thank you.

Comment: Which hash_map and what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

The STL containers (if that's what you're using) are not thread-safe.

size() is likely to walk the buckets and count the numbers. Modifying that data structure while another thread walks it is dangerous (that is, dangerous like a drunk elephant in a minefield).

I'd recommend wrapping your hash_map with some functions that update the count separately, as an atomic integer. That value will not be exact, but probably will be close enough, and it will reduce thread contention between size() and insert/erase operations.

Comment: I'm not clear why the walking through the buckets and count the numbers would modify something in that structure?

Comment: @longbkit: The other threads will modify the structure, as you stated in your question. You cannot have other threads accessing the data if one thread is writing to it, at least not without taking special measures such as locking or using a thread-safe hash_map from the beginning.

Comment: hello, as I see then size() function just return a local variable of hash_map, so I think no problem in my case. Any idea?

Comment: @longbkit: Well, that might work for you. Reading it should not hurt too much anyhow, and as you don't need full precision, it might be off by a bit but not too much (if you're doing a lot of other thread-synchronization now and then). It depends on your application, OS and hardware. It won't be bullet-proof unless you code for it properly, which is keeping a separate atomically updated size variable. (That way, memory read/write fences are set up correctly, etc... advanced stuff.)

Comment: @longbkit: Well, I can't stop you from trying. Please code responsibly though. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This strongly depends on the type of your hash_map. If it's `std::unordered_map`, then the answer is **NO** --- concurrent calls to member functions from separate threads are not permitted if any of those is a non-`const` member function.

If, on the other hand, you are using a type designed for concurrent access, then the answer may very well be yes.

Comment: I just declare like this: typedef hash_map <{hidden}, {hidden}> m_hash. What type of this hash_map is? I don't know if a hash_map can be unordered_map or not!

Comment: A compiler-provided `hash_map` type is unlikely to be thread-safe. Such types are usually called something like `concurrent_hash_map`.

Comment: I thought concurrent access was allowed as long as none of the accesses were mutating.  (I don't think that's the case here, but your statements suggests that even if all accesses were reads, it wouldn't be permitted.)

Comment: @James: You are right --- concurrent calls to `const` member functions of standard containers are permitted provided that there are no concurrent mutating calls.